# Project ID for analyzing somatic mutation data from TCGA with Bioquery

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am using [bigrquery package](https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery), trying to analyze the somatic mutation data following the instructions from [here](https://github.com/isb-cgc/examples-R/blob/master/inst/doc/Somatic_Mutations.md).

However, I do not know how to get my own *project* name?

My code so far:

```
querySql <- paste("SELECT * FROM ",mutTable," limit 1", sep="")
result <- query_exec(querySql, project=project)     ##the project name
data.frame(Columns=colnames(result))
```

Comment: From the manuals it can be just any string, have you tried?

Comment: If it is the R project you want, it is the name of the .Rproj file in your working directory. getwd() to see your working directory.